# Unable to build Sitecore Habitat solution

Tags: gulp, sitecore, sitecore-habitat

I tried to set up Sitecore Habitat solution by using the default configuration but unfortunately when i try the third task Publish All Projects the build fails showing the below error:

```
> cmd.exe /c gulp -b "C:\Projects\Habitat" --color --gulpfile "C:\Projects\Habitat\Gulpfile.js" 03-Publish-All-Projects
[11:12:23] Using gulpfile C:\Projects\Habitat\Gulpfile.js
[11:12:23] Starting '03-Publish-All-Projects'...
[11:12:23] Starting 'Build-Solution'...
[11:12:23] Using automatic maxcpucount
[11:12:23] { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }
[11:12:23] Build failed!
[11:12:23] 'Build-Solution' errored after 101 ms
[11:12:23] Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
[11:12:23] '03-Publish-All-Projects' errored after 112 ms
[11:12:23] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(Build-Solution)'
Message:
    spawn ENOENT
Details:
    code: ENOENT
    errno: ENOENT
    syscall: spawn
Stack:
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
Process terminated with code 1.
```

The enviorement that i have set up is identical as described on the following link https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like npm modules gulp is not found. 
If you have installed npm module add the following to the path in the environment varriable:%AppData%\npm

Note: Do not forget to close and re-open cmd (or VS2015).

Comment: If the comment above does not help you try to install gulp-cli package:

npm install -g gulp-cli